# QML Arabic font rendering incorrectly in iOS

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qtandroidextras, qfont

There seems to be difference in font rendering with QML in ios and android as given below

This one is correctly rendered  in android

[image]

Please check the difference in ios. Here its showing incorrectly.

[image]

Do i have to do anything different in iOS for properly displaying? Or does this have to do anything with language support.

Below is the code used.

```
FontLoader 
{
     id: fontArabicSoq
     source: "qrc:/fonts/quran_soq.OTF"
}                 

Text 
{
      id: dataText
      font.pointSize: Qt.platform.os == 'osx' ? 27 : slider1.value
      font.family:  fontArabicSoq.name  //'Al Bayan'  --> osx
      renderType: Text.NativeRendering
      font.styleName: 'Medium'
      font.weight: Font.Thin
      text: modelData.word                                                
}
```

Comment: As I see the characters are correct, the problem with diacritics only. As I know to write Arabic characters using Unicode several signs are used. So maybe the the font engine on iOS interprets diacritics different. Did you have the issue with standard font? or maybe the problem is that Qt Unicode is outdated, as I see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33764), for example.

Comment: Standard fonts are okay, its when using other fonts like [Quranic_fonts](http://tanzil.net/docs/quranic_fonts) there are diacritics issues as you said. So its a Qt issue?